# How to add new column and custom attribute in order email template in Magento 1.9.3?

Tags: product-attribute, order-email, transactional-mail, magento1.9.3

[image]

In this new order email.

I want to add a column in this table where i want to show a custom product attribute..

Please tell me how can i add column inside the new Order confirmation email template so it will show another column and attribute

already tried  editing

```
app/design/frontend/template/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

and template files in `app/locale` folder.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Comment: @PawanKParmar - no I haven't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Consideration:code of custom attribute is custom
```

> Note: Please do not edit core files, Copy below files to your Theme

First we need to add a column to template:

```
file path:app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items.phtml
```

add below code before Qty th

```
<th class="cell-name align-center">
   <?php echo $this->__('Custom'); ?>
</th>
```

Now we need to get value of custom attribute.file that is responsible for getting all attribute values is:

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

In above file when you log $_item, it will default not having value of custom attribute.So what we need is to load product and get value of product custom attribute. for that you need to add below code before Qty td:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku()); ?>
//load product by sku

<td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_product->getCustom(); ?></td>
//add td column with attribute value
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml**

as you suggested, I have added this code in this file before getqtyordered()`<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku()); ?>

<td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_product->getCustom(); ?></td>

<td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $product->getAttributeText('hsn_type');?> </td>
   
<td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></td>`
it's not working, am i doing something wrong

Comment: @Aks, Why you are putting  <td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_product->getCustom(); ?></td> in your code ? if attribute code id 'hsn_type' then you can use  <td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_product->getHsnType(); ?>.

Comment: @Aks, what is type of your custom attribute ?

Comment: Attribute Code (hsn_type) and Product type - simple product

Comment: I am asking about attribute type e.g text or drop-down or multi-select

Comment: drop-down and input validation - letters & numbers

Comment: working fine below code:
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku()); ?>

<td class="cell-content align-center"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('hsn_type'); ?></td>

Comment: Thanks code is working but When I change it in my base file but it is not working in my rwd theme.

Comment: If you have custom theme, copy these file in your theme with same location and try.