# Magento 1: Add custom attribute in transactional e-mail

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, cache, invoice, transactional-mail

In transactional mail, I need to add a custom attribute.

I modified the below files 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml

But changes are not reflecting on a mail.

I also flushed the Magento cache.

How can I modify transactional mail?

Comment: Hello @Shesh, do you want to add a new column in sales email ?

Comment: Please try : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182759/how-to-add-new-column-and-custom-attribute-in-order-email-template-in-magento-1/184789#184789

Comment: @Pawan checked as per your suggestion, My problem is that changes are not reflecting on email template. even though I renamed the default.phtml and item.phtml file but still got a mail in my mail id.

Comment: I have been seeing this problem since three days ;(

Comment: may be file you are editing from wrong theme OR may be there is cache issue.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/magento-hackathon/E-MailPreview extension for debug.

Comment: I flush the Magento cache.. without extension is it not possible?

Comment: this extension is only for debug. In admin you can check how email template will look with actual data.

Comment: first make sure you are editing right file.

Comment: okay, I'll add this extension...