# Attribute info in email

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, email

How can I add this part, it is a child attribute 
[image]

Into email, which is sent to customers? Unfortunately now I have only the name, and sku in the email

[image]

Comment: By default Magento renders the parent product with the selected options in the emails. That's done by the default item renderer (class `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Default` and template `template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`).It looks like you have customized the emails and either overwritten the renderers or removed them.

Comment: please try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182759/how-to-add-new-column-and-custom-attribute-in-order-email-template-in-magento-1/184789#184789

Answer (score 0):

I paste this code into items.phtml and still got nothing in the email.

Can You tell me where is the mistake:
[image]