# how to add variant description into email

Tags: email

How can I add this part ( it is a variant of parent product which customer bought)

[image]

Into a transation email. Right now I have only The basic name and the sku
[image]

Comment: Same question as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269899/attribute-info-in-email but differnet user? Please consider my comment in that question and check your customizations

Comment: I paste this code into items.phtml and still got nothing in the email.

Can You tell me where is the mistake:

Comment: <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                        <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif ?>